# Get the Access Token in Stripe payment gateway in PHP

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

I am very new to the curl and i need to send the POST request to the following url:

`curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=Secret key \
  -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code`

in the response i will be receiving the access token from the stripe.
please let me know how can create the function in php to do the same using the php - cURL.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you seen this gist: https://gist.github.com/amfeng/3507366 ?

Comment: thanks koopajah will try with this and let if its success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe would probably advise to use their libraries but this is a curl tool I've been playing with here this morning; I prefer curl over libraries that wrap around it any day:

```
$post = 'client_secret='.$system['stipe']['client_secret'].'&grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_GET['code'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $system['stipe']['token_url']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You just need to wrap it up as a function and json_decode the values returned.

This works for me whereas the code in the docs / gist didn't as they were lacking the false flag on the SSL verify peer which in my dev setup here made things prang.

Comment: Disabling for your dev setup is ok but you should definitely not advise `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` in production I think